# Too many files in a folder caused system failure (Debian)

Tags: filesystems, hard-disk, hardware

I'm running a Debian web server and my caching system created millions of files in a "cache" folder. 
Suddenly, the system was unable to run anymore and I wasn't able to address it via SSH. Reboots didn't help.

My Hoster analyzed my system and told me that my hard disks are damaged. With a rescue system I was able to backup the system and to clear the cache. After a reboot, the system is able to run again without any errors.

How can this be explained? Can too many files cause a system failure and some subfolders would prevent this problem?
Or are my hard disks really damaged and how can be explained that the system runs without errors again?

Some tips to check my hard disks?

Comment: Assuming your filesystem was ext*, I doubt this was a filesystem-level problem. I recommend you learn to use and understand the output of `smartctl` (available under the smartmontools package) to check the health of your drives (assuming you're running on bare metal and not in a VM. If your being hosted in a VM, it's your provider's responsibility to keep the hardware healthy).

Comment: It's worth noting, if your host is running on a VM (quite common with web hosting companies, for example) the smartctl commands won't be able to read the actual underlying physical hardware.

Comment: It's not hosted on a vm. Thank you for your answers, i will check this out and write you again.

Comment: I believe that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466521/how-many-files-can-i-put-in-a-directory) topic is related to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your hosting provider told you that the hard disks were physically damaged or failed, the issue you've described is completely unrelated to the number of files you put on the drive, the filesystem, the cache, or any other software related issue.  Mechanical failures of hardware do happen on occasion.  "Too many files" may have an impact on various system operations, but it's not a common problem, and certainly won't cause your hard drives to become damaged.

@Dylan is correct, if you have access to the bare metal node via ssh, the smartctl package contains monitoring tools that can verify the physical health of your hard drives.  If your hosting provider gives you ssh access to a VM (virtualbox, VMware, Xen, whatever) then it's highly unlikely you will be able to see the physical hardware your system lives on.